# What is the first game with explicit fluff/crunch distinctions?

Tags: system-agnostic, history-of-gaming

I find myself involved in discussions frequently where one person will claim that a piece of text in a rulebook is "just fluff" or "pure flavor" and can be "refluffed" by the players with little or no DM oversight, while others are "mechanics" or "crunch" that requires a house-rule to change.

Specifically, the things cited as "fluff" are those that do not have an attached dice roll or explicit benefit/penalty listed. Things like the descriptions of classes, feats or spells/other abilities. On the other hand, "mechanics" or "crunch" includes rule text that has direct, explicit application to the game world, especially when expressed in pseudo-mathematical form (such as dice rolls, damage, or bonuses and penalties).

I know that 4e had a specific rule that said that descriptive text in *italics* in an ability entry or elsewhere was just an example (ie fluff) and could be changed at will. But I'm pretty sure that this distinction pre-dates 4e--I remember hearing it invoked to justify taking prestige classes (3.5e) completely out of context and apply them without satisfying the "fluff" prerequisites (such as meeting/being trained by someone of the appropriate faction).

What is the earliest system  have this distinction explicitly in the ruleset? Ideal answers would have citations or quotations to where that's defined in the rules. And exact wording ("fluff") isn't important, but the rule text must explicitly set certain portions of the ruleset as being able to be changed by players without DM (if any such role exists in the system) intervention.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110913/discussion-on-question-by-benjamin-t-hall-when-did-the-idea-of-a-fluff-or-flavo).

Comment: I have re-rolled it to the current version. The reasons are: the previous state of the question got closed, and then got a failed re-open. At its current state, it got 4 reopen votes, and I was going to give it the fifth before the rollback, so I think the community agrees that the current state is better, overall.

Comment: One problematic aspect of the question is that these distinctions are used to adapt the game to a player group, they exist more as a characterization levied by rules readers rather than their makers. The players not the creators. Many RPG will indicate that a part of the text is ‘setting’ as opposed to ‘game rules’ but would never refer to anything in their game as ‘fluff’ due to the negative connotation.

Comment: Would someone care to explain how they understood this question as a game-rec question? Either way, @OP: You may want to clarify that you are not interested in an infinite list of all possible games that make this distinction, but which one is most likely to be the first to introduce such distinction **explicitly**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110922/discussion-between-please-stop-being-evil-and-hellsaint).

Comment: @BenjaminTHall What system do you find this issue coming up in? I can give you an answer to your discussion in 5e: there is no fluff. I think looking for an answer to that would be more beneficial and easier than listing all systems that have fluff/crunch distinctions. What would you like to get out of this question?

Comment: @BenjaminTHall - What about systems which achieve the same thing by coming at it from the opposite direction? I can't think of any systems offhand which directly say "this is fluff, this is crunch", but I can think of several which say "we're just giving you the raw mechanics of how these things work [crunch], it's up to you to decide what they look like in your game [fluff]". They often have a few examples of how you could flavor the mechanics, but they are clearly just that, examples, and not "canonical fluff", for lack of a better term.

Comment: "First game" is pretty broad: the names of chaturanga pieces are "fluff" and can be renamed to reflavor the game without affecting the mechanics. Games are very strongly powered by metaphor and flavor laid over but separable from mechanics, and have been since before recorded history. What scope are you considering here? First tabletop RPG to have fluff distinct from crunch? (It's almost certainly the first thing we'd consider to be a tabletop RPG at all.)

Comment: @doppelgreener I think they implicitly mean RPG system here. The names of OD&D PCs are also fluff, but you gotta get an explicit quote to that effect now. Basically we are looking for the first RPG to talk down to players in a manual or peripheral (Gygax did a lot of talking down, so I'm hoping to find something like that player rather than DM directed in an ancilliary work)

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil So the first game to distinctly say in its own text “these parts of the game are mechanically insignificant flavor and you can change them as you like without affecting their function, and these parts of the game are mechanically significant and you cannot change those without affecting function”, and draw and maintain a clear and explicit separation? (Like D&D 4e did, and like D&D 5e does not?) Although, it kind of goes without saying that changing the names of things does not (usually) impact their function, for example.

Comment: @doppelgreener and please stop being evil FWIW the OP has stated in chat: "[...] To me, all text is rules in absence of a meta-rule saying otherwise. [...]" and "But as pedantic and missing-the-point as people are being about this, I don't even care any more. If it closes, I'm not going to put any more effort into trying to reopen it."

Comment: Ok, this question is now closed for the second time, and some 40 comments have been spilled over it. I'm gonna suggest someone opens a meta at this point, rather than keeping at it in the comments.